# How to "iterate" over this set

Tags: c++, combinations

Hello say I have some data `A -> ....` (n data points). Now I take from this data a given number of values (m) - and now I wish to iterate over all unique combinations of these values.

An example for 5 values where you take 2 unique:
A unique combination would be a something like "a + b" or "a + c"  - however "c + d" is the same as "b + c". And "B + E" is the same as "A + D"

```
A x x x x 
B x       x x
C   x     x 
D     x     x
E       x
```

Those describe some geometrical "lines", and the whole specimen can be "mirrored" around the middle point. So for an arbitrary number of lines, is there a clever algorithm to iterate over everything considering this "mirror ability"?

And what is a formula to calculate the number of elements given the set size n and the number of items m?

---- an example with "3 out 6":
It also resembles closely the function combine(6,3) - however now I marked the duplicate rows with - instead of x.

```
                    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
A x x x x x x x x - -                     A
B x x x x             x x - - - -         B
C x       x x x       x x -       - - -   C
D   x     x     x -   x     - -   - -   - D
E     x     x   x   -   x   -   - -   - - E
F       x     x   - -     -   - - - - - - F
```

So possible list would be:

ABC, ABD, ABE, ABF, ACD, ACE, ACF, ADE, BCD, BCE

10 out of 20 potential candidates ignoring the symetry.

Comment: Why is B+E the same as A+D?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth When you flip B + E around the middle ("C" in this example, with even numbers it would be between two lines). B converts to D and E converts to A.

Comment: Oh I see.  Well in that case, draw an NxN grid, and put an X in all coordinates corresponding to a combination that you want to generates.  The pattern should be obvious at that point.

Comment: I can't figure out how the grid shown matches any part of the description.  This question makes almost no sense to me

Comment: Is this how the sample works with 2 elements from a set of five? http://ideone.com/No3iA2

Comment: Wait, I fail to see how it's mirrored.  Wouldn't mirroring create duplicates?

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, that would be a set (of 6 though :P)... Mirroring is just what I "prevent", the geometrical real body can be mirrored, so the heavy calculations that I would have to do on each (finite element analysis taking upto an hour to complete) would be best if the amount of calculations can be limited by not doing them.

Comment: So, it looks like you want to find all the combinations with unique differences between the 2 values.  In your examples, this fits with "c, d" and "b, c".  There is only a difference of 1 for both cases.  Same with "B, E" and "A, D" .  In this case there is a difference of 3 between the values of B, E as well as A, D.  Is this correct?  If so, then can there be other cases where you might be taking unique differential combinations with more than 2 at a time?  If so, then how would unique differentials be calculated?  Can you give an example of a case with 3 at a time?

Comment: This one is... really hard....

Comment: @BobBryan: I think this is the example: http://ideone.com/No3iA2, but the pattern is... complicated.

Comment: @Mooing Duck The link you gave generates all the combinations for the N choose K problem.  It has little to do with this question.

Comment: @BobBryan: yes, this question is _incredibly_ close to the N choose K problem, except he needs the indexes to not be reflective around the center.  Notice that 6 choose 2 contains AB but NOT EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.  In fact it's quite difficult.  But here's the rundown:

```
for_each_unmirrored() 
   mark first element as part of the set.
   mark last element as definitely NOT part of the set.
   //we know no matter whats inside, this isnt't semetrical, so all combinations
   for_each_mirrored() on all elements between these.

   mark first element as part of the set.
   mark last element as part of the set.
   //ends are semetrical, so insides cannot be
   for_each_unmirrored() on all elements between these

   mark first element as definitely not part of the set.
   mark last element as definitely not in the set.
   //ends are semetrical, so insides cannot be
   for_each_unmirrored() on all elements between these

for_each_mirrored() 
    for each element
        mark it as part of the set.
        if more elements are needed
            for_each_mirrored on elements to the right but in range
```

Yeah, even the abreviated pseudocode is complicated. The real code is here: http://ideone.com/WDEn40 (including showing that it works for 6 elements pick 3).  The linked code isn't as simple as it could be, because I optimized it to avoid allocations and minimize function calls.  (As a side effect, the `for_each_call_helper` isn't threadsafe.  If this needs to be threadsafe, simply remove the `static` keyword from the variables in this function.)

Answer (score 0):

I confess that I don't fully understand the question either.  However, the general way to solve problems like this is to come up with a good notation and a canonical form, and an algorithm to convert something to canonical form.  Then you just do the heavy stuff on canonical forms, and don't repeat.